# Printing element of list in single line without any loop

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to print all element of list without any loop in python.
And i got this on internet.
let list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and print(*list).
But i don't know what this '*' doing here.

Answer (score 2):

**printing the list using * operator separated by space**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   
print(*a)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

**printing the list using * and sep operator**

```
print(*a, sep = ", ")
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

**print in new line**

```
print(*a, sep = "\n")
```

Output:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

Comment: What this '*  mean here?

Comment: @RitikKumar I believe this will provide you with all the information you need avout splat (*) in python: https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558